# Rust can't link bindings to C library

Tags: linker, rust, ffi

I followed the [rust-bindgen](https://github.com/servo/rust-bindgen) tutorial to make bindings for [the scrypt C library](http://github.com/Tarsnap/scrypt). I can't run my test because of linking error:

```
/home/user/project/rust-scrypt/src/lib.rs:32: undefined reference to `crypto_scrypt'
      collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

and my test:

```
include!(concat!(env!("OUT_DIR"), "/bindings.rs"));
// ...
// ...
#[test]
fn test_script() {
  let mut kdf_salt = to_bytes("fd4acb81182a2c8fa959d180967b374277f2ccf2f7f401cb08d042cc785464b4");
    let passwd = "1234567890";
    let mut buf = [0u8; 32];

    unsafe {
        crypto_scrypt(passwd.as_ptr(), passwd.len(), kdf_salt.as_mut_ptr(), kdf_salt.len(),
                      2, 8, 1, buf.as_mut_ptr(), 32);
    }

    println!(">> DEBUG: {:?}", buf);
    // "52a5dacfcf80e5111d2c7fbed177113a1b48a882b066a017f2c856086680fac7");
}
```

The bindings have been generated and exist in `bindings.rs`. I don't know why the linker throws an error.

Here is my [builds.rs](https://gist.github.com/r8d8/c94520390008dacf6845f93a3122a7aa)

```
extern crate bindgen;

use std::env;
use std::path::PathBuf;

fn main() {
    let out_path = PathBuf::from(env::var("OUT_DIR").unwrap());
    let bindings = bindgen::Builder::default()
        .no_unstable_rust()
        .header("wrapper.h")
        .generate()
        .expect("Unable to generate bindings");

    bindings
        .write_to_file(out_path.join("bindings.rs"))
        .expect("Couldn't write bindings!");
}
```

And my [Cargo.toml](https://gist.github.com/r8d8/fb5d9c1b7c3f905a7a2e7870dbd29967)

```
[package]
name = "rust-scrypt"
version = "0.0.1"
build = "build.rs"

[build-dependencies]
bindgen = "0.23"
```

Comment: While you're at it, please include the version of that library (are you building it against the master branch)?

Comment: yeap, using master

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Please re-familiarize yourself with [the "Building some native code" case study](http://doc.crates.io/build-script.html#case-study-building-some-native-code). Specifically, you have informed Rust what the *interface* of the library is, but you haven't told the compiler *where the code is*. That's what the error you are getting says: "I can't find the implementation of `crypto_scrypt`"

You need to add the library to the *linker path* and instruct it to be linked against.

From the linked case study, your build script can inform the compiler where the library is and what to link against:

```
println!("cargo:rustc-link-search=native={}", path_to_library);
println!("cargo:rustc-link-lib=static=hello"); // the name of the library
```

**Please, please, *please*** read the section about [`*-sys` packages](http://doc.crates.io/build-script.html#-sys-packages) which documents the best practices for this type of integration. Namely, your Cargo.toml is missing the [links key](http://doc.crates.io/build-script.html#the-links-manifest-key), which is going to cause problems if anyone ever tries to link in this library multiple times.

--

Note that there are already [crates that purport to provide scrypt](https://crates.io/search?q=scrypt).

Comment: I'm migrating from `rust-crypto`, because he is to slow, roughly 100 times slower than Go implementation of same algorithm. Other crates either based on rust-crypto or not mature enough. I already spended some time for investigation for this stuff)